# Improving GitHub webpage update rate

Tags: github-actions, github-pages

I am trying to build a static website with GitHub pages. Because the website basically provides some statistical information about the current market status, it is crucial to update its content as often as possible (ideally every ~0-5 minutes). The website is made out of several webpages (html files) that could be independently updated from one another. As of now, the whole website (every html file) is generated/update via a ressource-intensive GitHub action that takes about 10 minutes to run and produces all the html files. Each html file is quite large (~15mb).

There are several issues here:

- GitHub actions schedules are unreliable (sometimes they even take more than 1h to trigger)
- The GitHub action takes quite some time to be carried out, this could be partly solved by generating each html file with an independent GitHub action
- Because the html files are so large, it takes quite some time for the website to be deployed

My attempt to solve these issues:
I created 4 new GitHub accounts (lets call them 'working repositories') and each of them is running the same GitHub actions that generates all the html files and then pushes them to the main repository where my website is located. Each 'working repository' action is scheduled every ~15 minutes. (I created independent accounts because I believe that I would have more chances that the GitHub action is executed than if I just created 4 actions in the main repository, maybe I am wrong about this...).

This solution has been working so far but it is not optimal. One issue is that it still takes too long for the GitHub action to run since it has to update every page. I could of course create an action for each html file. However, the problem is that as more GitHub actions are run and more html files are pushed to the main directory, the likelihood of a push occurring while the website is being deployed becomes higher, and this will cancel the website deployment since the files have been updated. Another issues (which is not critical at this point) is that it is hard to maintain 4 separate GitHub accounts with exactly the same repositories, and this will worsen as the website grows.

How can I improve this? I am totally aware that GitHub pages are not ment to be updated that often. However, I lack the resources to get my own server running and have to rely on GitHub for the moment.

Any input to improve this workflow would be very helpful!

Comment: I think (even if I not work with github pages) that maybe you can dynamically load the content, instead of changing the page

Comment: I would use a self-hosted runner.

Comment: @JohnHanley could you provide me more information or a reference on that?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners

Comment: Connect it to a data source, perhaps a file that lives in another github repo. Use javascript to load and render instead of updating your html and rebuild? since the data is short lived as you said, you don't need SEO for the data which does not need to be part of static content.